# What is the minima rule for a Metal 1 layer for the 2 contacts on a poly shown on the figure? I'm using 0.18um library

Tags: layout, cadence, dimensions, design-rules, virtuoso

[Contact on a poly using 0.06 spacing for the metal 1 layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOo2V.png)
[image: Contact on a poly using 0.06 & 0.005 spacing for the metal 1 layer]

Comment: Generally speaking, noone can tell you. That highly depends on the specific technology you're using. Your technology PDK should include design rules for that or at least specify them in a PDF or something.

Comment: Please don’t write your question as a title. Include all relevant information in the actual post.